# Prevent scroll bar appearing

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, c#-4.0, scrollbar

I am developing a website in asp.net; and on this page is the collapsable panel control installed from ajax. My question is, when i open the panel (in which there is a few labels) the scroll bar appears on the side of the page, and the page shifts. This looks unclean. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the scrollbar from appearing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you specify which scroll you are talking about(browser scroll etc) or at least share a screen?

Comment: Hi, i am talking about the browser scroll bar apearing when the panel opens. I though it might have something to do with the fact that the contents is shifting off the height.

Comment: It's hard to find solution for your problem knowing nothing about structure and layout of your site. Please share a screen of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about disabling the browser scroll bar you can add `overflow-y: hidden` to your `html` element in css.

**Caution -** this will disable scrolling on the website.

Comment: Hi, i dont really want to disable it for the whole website. It works, but i shall just leav it for now. It was only going to be a temp fix anyway. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to disable it, you can use the `overflow-y: scroll` mentioned by Zielun. This will always show the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent from appearing and disappearing a scrollbar you can just enable it to be always there.

```
html {overflow-y:scroll}
```

It should help with the effect of moving site to the left or right depending on scrollbar appearance. Hope it helps.